# Entity Framework, provider failed to Open

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I got this error:

```
-InnerException {"Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=86; handshake=2368; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=12018; "}  System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}
```

From this:

```
       DataSourceContext Context = new DataSourceContext();
        var Booklist = Context.Booklists.ToList();
        Context.Dispose();
        Parallel.ForEach(Booklist, currentBook =>
        {
            switch (currentBook.FKcatalogNum)
            {
                case 0:
                    {
                       ...

                        finally
                        {

                                currentBook.BookDetails = Models.DBBookSourceInitializer.GetBookReaderNet(currentBook.Link);
                                try
                                {
                                    context.Booklists.AddOrUpdate(currentBook);
                                    context.SaveChanges();
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    ...

                                    context.Booklists.AddOrUpdate(currentBook);
                                    context.SaveChanges();

                            }
                            context.Dispose();
                        }
                        break;
```

Im trying to take all the book titles from the database, and add details about their summary, chapters, number of pages etc. But I keep getting connection error. There's thousands of books, and after a certain amount of stuff processed it gives me this error. Judging from the primary key of the last book processed, it's 1180, so that means that 1180 books went fine and then suddenly this.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or what I should be changing.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you disposing the context before using it?

Comment: I'm not? the "..." means some code I ommited, and I'm using them in the try-catch block before I dispose it?

Comment: Reproduce this error with a much shorter piece of code, and post that one instead of the long version.